# Change cmake generated project files directory

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I could not find any question that was helpful concerning my question, so here it is (or prove me wrong).

First: I do everything under Windows and build only for Visual Studio.
My Situation: I have my main directory which contains a "main" CMakeLists. So here is were to make the cmake call and it does not much itself:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.1)
project (EulerAdventureReinvented)

if (CMAKE_GENERATOR MATCHES Win64)
    set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/Win64/")
    set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/Win64/")
    set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/Win64/")
else()
    set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/Win32/")
    set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/Win32/")
    set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/Win32/")
endif()

add_subdirectory(source)
```

But it adds another CMakeLists in the source directory which does the setup for the "main" project. So it contains the add_executable call and I wanna keep it that way. But the problem is that it does write the vcxproj files, CMakeFiles dir into that source directory, but I want them in the root directory or... well just somewhere else.

**Final Question:** What do I need to set for this? I mean which variable is the one I want to change. I searched and found so many that I came to a point of trial and error and even then did not find my files somewhere else.

EDIT: I changed the title a bit to avoid confusion between build and generated files. I do not want to set the build path, since that is already done by the above code.

Comment: You set the build folder in `cmake-gui` before you configure and generate the project. It's recommended that the build folder is not the same as the folder containing the source code.

Comment: @drescherjm I do not use the cmake gui, cause I believe that a gui should not be necessary and I am interested of the cmake code itself. So or so the build path is not what I wanna set, this is already done by the cmake code I put into my question. My question is concerning the project files

Comment: The project files and all generated output are put in the build directory tree. That has nothing to do with the variables you have set.

Comment: You can't change the build folder in a `CMakeLists.txt`. That is set when `CMake` configures your project the first time. You need to reconfigure setting a new build folder. You can do this with cmake or cmake-gui

Comment: @drescherjm Okay and how "You need to reconfigure setting a new build folder." do I do this in cmake, which variable is the one I wanna set? I searched a related post with a lot of this variables and none worked.

Comment: @drescherjm and where do I set it. I got this project setup idea from a project I am working on and I just cannot find where they are setting this up, but they are including a dependencies.cmake file in the main CMakeLists.txt . But you are kind of implying it cannot be done there, so do I need to wrap the setup with a bat file?

Comment: When you run `cmake` run it from the folder that you want to be the build folder with a single command line argument that is the folder of your source code.If you use cmake-gui the top edit control is the source folder the bottom one is the build folder

Comment: If you are using the Visual Studio 2017 integration and not using `CMake` directly you need to set the buildRoot. See "CMake settings and custom configurations" in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/cmake-tools-for-visual-cpp?view=vs-2017

Comment: @drescherjm okay, yeah I did it like you said, just wrapped it with a batch that does this weird cd changes, but now it works thx

Comment: You may have to set the Generator command line argument to CMake. I forgot to add that. This is if you have more than 1 compiler found or the default choice is not what you want ( probably 32 bit application).

Comment: @drescherjm what I did was create a batch in the root directory that creates the folder where all the files are hidden goes in there with cd and calls cmake in the root directory from there, like you said.
Then it creates a link to the solution in the root directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CMake 3.13.2 the following switches are available:

`cmake [<options>] -S <path-to-source> -B <path-to-build>`

So in the case you described above it would be something like:

`cmake -S . -B .\build`

Now, there is no variable for setting `<path-to-build>` but you can get it's information from `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`.  The variables you are setting control where artifacts wind up but not where project files are created or intermediate files are located.